# Image Layering How to

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010

I am totally new to web application programming, though I have been working with Windows application development for some time.
I am working in Visual Studio 2010 using aspx pages and Javascript.
I am trying to set up a forum style website where one of the functions would be to allow a user to display a scanned document, click on the document and place another image on top on the first document that would reference a note to be entered by that user. Similar to a footnote.
I have been able to get the xy coordinates of where the user clicks on the document, but have not been able to then place the small footnote image at the coordinates of the mouse click.
I have searched quite a bit for methods to do this, but have not found anything that I was able to adapt to my specific need.
The code that I have to get the coordinates and attempt to place "Image1" on the form follows.
I am also open to any suggestions of a better way to annotate the uploaded form.
Any assistance is appreciated.

```
    <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ImageTestaspx.aspx.vb" Inherits="Coder2Coder.ImageTestaspx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onMousebtClick(event) {
            //right click, capture coordinates of click
                pos_x = event.offsetX ? (event.offsetX) : event.pagex - document.getElementById("pointer_div").offsetLeft;
                pos_y = event.offsetY ? (event.offsetY) : event.pageY - document.getelementById("pointer_div").offsetTop;
                document.getElementById("Image1").style.left = (pos_x);
                document.getElementById("Image1").style.top = (pos_y);
                document.getElementById("Image1").style.visibility = "visible";
                //alert(pos_x,pos_y);
                //break;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" runat="server">
    <div id="pointer_div" onclick="onMousebtClick(event)" style="background-image:url('/images/holhours.bmp');width:899px;height:718px;">

        <img src="/images/1.jpg" alt="No Image" id="Image1" style="position:relative;visibility:hidden;z-index:2;" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pos_x` and `pos_y` are `Number`s. Elements are styled using `String`s with some unit. You're missing `px`.

Change

`document.getElementById("Image1").style.left = (pos_x);`

to

`document.getElementById("Image1").style.left = (pos_x + "px");`

and

`document.getElementById("Image1").style.top = (pos_y);`

to

`document.getElementById("Image1").style.top = (pos_y + "px");`

The image element would also need to be positioned absolutely in a relatively positioned container.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m994sr2d/1/

Comment: Great. Also, if a response answers your question, please mark it as such by clicking the check-mark to the left of the respective answer.